# Найти пару чисел разных знаков в массиве

Tags: c++, массивы

**Задание:** Определить количество пар двух одинаковых чисел разных знаков в массиве.
Также была идея что один цикл идет с начала, второй с конца, и ищет пары, но так из за размера массива и количества чисел меньше или больше ноля, такие пары могут и не встретиться. Нужна помощь как это решить.

Пример: имеется упорядоченный массив {-10, -10, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 10 }, то результатом должно быть число 5 (количество пар). Все пары: (-10, 10); (-10, 10); (-1, 1); (-1, 1); (-1, 1).

**code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    
    int N;
    cout << "Enter array size: "; 
    cin >> N;
    
    int *arr = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        arr[i] = (rand() % 20) - 10; // nums in range from -10 to 10
        
    int num_of_pairs = 0; // var for calculating number of pairs    
        
    // solution here    
        
    delete[] arr;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136488/discussion-on-question-by-lcashe-------).

Answer (score 1):

> Старый вариант. Если массив { -1, -1, -1, 1, 1 }, то результатом программы будет 2.

Перед этим необходимо отсортировать массив и подключить математическую библиотеку. Вроде работает, пытался избежать большой вычислительной сложности, действуя по принципу сужения (Похоже на очень стремный велосипед=))

```
int lastIndex = sizeArr;

for (int i = 0; i < sizeArr && arr[i] < 0; ++i)
{
    int current = abs(arr[i]);

    for (int j = lastIndex - 1; j >= 0 && arr[j] > 0; --j)
        if (arr[j] == current)
        {
            pairs++;
            lastIndex = j;
            break;
        }
}
```

> UPD (Новый вариант):

Программа переделана под корректные условия.
Если массив { -1, -1, -1, 1, 1 }, то результатом программы будет 6 (Массив по прежнему необходимо отсортировать + подключить математическую библиотеку).

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeArr && arr[i] < 0; ++i)
{
    int current = abs(arr[i]);

    for (int j = sizeArr - 1; arr[j] > 0 && current <= arr[j]; --j)
        if (current == arr[j]) pairs++;
}
```

Comment: Да, не очень...  Если в массиве есть  -6, -5,  5,  5,  6, то  таких пар 3.  Каков  результат этого кода?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Интересно), если автору помогу вопрос, значит пары индивидуальны. Т.е -6 6 одна пара и -5 5 другая пара, а для оставшейся 5 нет пары.

Comment: устроить может все что угодно, когда человек сам не знает как и что решается.  Да и количество нужно, а не индекс одного элемента

Comment: @ARHovsepyan условие задачи изначально было некорректное, от этого и появилось множество решений, тк понимание у всех разное

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ:**

```
void positive_negative_pairs(int *arr, int N) {
    
    int *arr_copy = array_copying(arr, N);
    
    int PosNegPairs = 0;
    
for( int i = 0; i < N; i++){
   for(int j = i + 1; j < N; j++){
   
      if( -arr_copy[i] == arr_copy[j] || arr_copy[i] == -arr_copy[j] )
         PosNegPairs++;
   }
}

    cout << "Number of positive-negative pairs: " << PosNegPairs << endl;
    
    
    delete[] arr_copy;
}
```

Comment: Это O(N^2)... Кстати, а какой глубокий смысл в 1. копировании массива, 2. дублировании условия проверки в `if`?

Comment: Там 16 пунктов в задании. Для удобства кода все пункты были подразделены в функции. Основной массив в мейне. Копирую массив, т к при вызове функций в мейне структура первоначального массива меняется. Поэтому т к информация выводится в функции, достаточно выделить а после и освободить память для массива в функции, чтобы не деформировать первоначальный массив.

Comment: Тогда для гарантии неизменности исходного массива имеет смысл передавать `const int*`. Но зачем вот это дублирование: `-arr_copy[i] == arr_copy[j] || arr_copy[i] == -arr_copy[j]`?

Answer (score 0):

Просто и без сортировки:

```
const size_t size = std::size(arr);    
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size;  ++i)
    for (size_t j = i + 1; j < size; ++j)
        if (-arr[i] == arr[j] ) 
            ++k; 
cout << k;
```

Например в массиве `{ -2, 45, 34, 2, -2, 2, -2, 6, -34, 34, -6 }` есть `9` таких пар